# Transitioning from Main layout via button seems to break Radio Buttons in second Layout

Tags: java, android

*Full discloser*
 I have changed the title of the question to reflect the real issue at hand

It appears I am dumb somehow... so what I am doing wrong is related to how I transition between screens. When I made the code already shown to be the Main activity, everything seemed to run fine. So it has something to do with this.

```
        buttonArea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_area);

        }
    });
```

*OLD QUESTION INFORMATION about why radio buttons were not working in general.*

I have done some Android in the past and I have NO idea why what I am doing isn't working. This should be criminally simple...but for some reason its not working.

I should say there are no errors showing so everything is imported. I am using Android Studio.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_area);


    final RadioButton rb1 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radFeet);
    final RadioButton rb2 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radMeters);
    final EditText txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAreaIn);
    final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radGroupArea);

    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            double distance= Double.parseDouble(txt.getText().toString());
            if(rb1.isChecked()){
                txt.setText(String.valueOf(distance/con));
            }
            else if(rb2.isChecked()){
                txt.setText(String.valueOf(distance*con));
            }
        }

    });


}
```

Here is the XML of the activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="edu.gatech.seclass.converter.Area"
android:id="@+id/actArea">

<TextView android:text="@string/title_activity_area" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lblArea"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/txtAreaIn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblArea"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp" />


<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lblArea"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtAreaIn"
    android:minHeight="55dp"
    android:minWidth="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/radGroupArea">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Conv_to_feet"
        android:id="@+id/radFeet"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtAreaIn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        />


    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Conv_to_meters"
        android:id="@+id/radMeters"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radFeet"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false"
        />
</RadioGroup>
```

Yet when I click either of the Radio buttons... nothing ever happens. Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: try Toast something to see whether the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` is working

Comment: It didn't do it..whats more I made a toast outside of the setOnCheckChangeListener...and that didn't seem to pop the toast either.

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly the `android:checked="false"` that is causing the problem. Can you try remove it and see how it goes?

Comment: That didn't seem to make a bit of difference either.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that instead of switching Activities the way I was, I need to do it like this.

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Area.class));
```

Although slow, it does the job for this simple thing. still would be curious as to why the previous code will navigate to the correct layout but do nothing......Actually now that I think about it its probably because the class didn't change.